# Errors after upgrading to .Net 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I recently upgraded a project from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5.2.

I've just noticed that I'm getting Intellisense errors that do not show up as build errors.

On further investigation, I can see that my project is still referencing the 4.0 versions of Microsoft.CSharp.dll, WindowsBase.dll etc

Manually removing the references and adding the correct 4.5.2 assemblies does not work - the references always revert to the 4.0 assemblies.

Why is my project using the old assemblies? and how can I fix it?

--edit--
I added a new 4.5.2 class library project to my solution and it references the 4.0 assemblies too. Is my solution stuffed?

Comment: did you set your project's target framework to 4.5?also do you use resharper?

Comment: I set the project's target framework to 4.5.2. No, I don't use resharper.

Comment: try this: Close down visual studio,go to your project folder,show hidden files from folder options , go to .vs > ProjectName > .suo and cut this file to your desktop,and start the vs again and load your project.see if it helps your intellisense.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. Any idea about the referenced assemblies? That's bad, right?

Comment: just to be sure...what happens when u try to use the latest c# syntax? does it build?if so i have one more suggestion

Comment: The project builds after I add an async keyword to one of my methods. I see now that the Properties of the reference show that the 4.5.2 dll is in use. The Object Browser was confusing me. When I double click on the reference an incorrect path is shown in the Object Browser.

Comment: Ok. So it's just the intellisense. Which I guess I can ignore.. Unless you have any other ideas - thanks

Comment: Try going to import and export settings and setting your ide settings to defaults .. I ran into that problem a while back , deleted the suo file,and restored my settings,And restarted visual studio,it got fixed

Comment: No luck. I still see the Intellisense errors.